# Are closures different in node.js?

Tags: callback, node.js, closures

I have worked quite a lot with javascript but yesterday, I started using node.js. It's a little script that runs jslint on the files of a folder. For this example, I changed the command to call `ls` instead of `jslint`.

```
var sys = require("sys");
var fs = require("fs");
var cp = require('child_process');

var path = fs.realpathSync("./src/");

fs.readdir(fs.realpathSync("./src/"), function(err, files) {
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var filename = files[i];
    var complete = path + filename;

    // Run jslint on each file
    var jslint = cp.exec("ls " + complete, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
      console.log(filename + " : " + stdout);
    });    
  }
});
```

The output is this :

> jskata.nofreeze.js : /home/dan/php/jskata/src/jskata.undo.js
>
> jskata.nofreeze.js : /home/dan/php/jskata/src/jskata.nofreeze.js
>
> jskata.nofreeze.js : /home/dan/php/jskata/src/jskata.timezone.js

Why do the line `console.log(filename + " : " + stdout);` always prints `jskata.nofreeze.js` when the filename should obviously match the result of the `ls`? Are closures and scopes different in node.js than in javascript?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No they aren't any different, this is just the most common pitfall with closures in JavaScript.

See, you're in a loop, you're assigning the local variable `filename` on every iteration of the loop, therefore you're in fact overriding it's value. Since it's always the same local variable, and the closure works per reference, the value of `filename` inside the callback gets updates on each iteration of the loop.

'jskata.nofreeze.js' just happens to be the last file in the directory and therefore it's also the last value that gets assigned to `filename`.

To solve it you need to pass the value of `filename` *per* value:

```
// Run jslint on each file
(function(c, f) {
    cp.exec("cat " + c, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
      console.log(f + " : " + stdout);
    });
})(complete, filename);
```

This makes the whole thing work, even though it's a bit ugly. You can of course move this out into a named function if you don't want to clutter your inner loop with more anonymous functions.

Comment: Why is it actually, that this forces a per value pass? I've implemented the same before coming here, but came around to figure why exactly does it work compared to the naive (problem) implementation.

Answer (score 2):

you have slightly confusing code where you write this

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var filename = files[i];
```

because variables in javascript only have scope a the function level, so the filename variable is reused each time around the loop.

writing the code to this:

```
var filename;
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    filename = files[i];
```

might make it clearer where the problem is. and why as the previous answer suggests you need to pass filename to your function.